# Linq update error Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I am trying to update only one column which is EntityType. But i am getting this error while making the join and update statement.

**Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.**

```
 var entityCodesRepo = _context.EntityCodes.ToList();

   var qualifiedRecs = await (from px in searchQuery
                                    join ecx in entityCodesRepo on px.EntityCodeID equals ecx.EntityCodeID
                                       select new IDMS_Partner()
                                         {
                                          EntityType = ecx.DisplayLabel
                                         }
                                    ).ToListAsync();
```

Please suggest where am i making the mistake.

```
[Table("IDMS_Partner")]
    public partial class IDMS_Partner
    {
        [Key]
        public int PID { get; set; }
        public int EntityCodeID { get; set; }
        public string EntityType { get; set; }
     }
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework or LinqToSql?

Comment: The data is being pulled with the help of Entity framework only

Comment: Which version? EF 6 or Core?

Comment: EF 6 is being used

Comment: Please show the definition of `IDMS_Partner` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't join `IQueryable` with `IEnumerable` in Linq-to-Entities so you should not materialize `EntityCodes` using `ToList` before joining with `searchQuery`. The second thing is that in EF 6 you can't really create partial entities inside a query (this is not true in EF Core though) so if `IDMS_Partner` belongs to the context you will get an error so either use an anonymous type or some DTO class. So finally your query should look like this:

```
var entityCodesRepo = _context.EntityCodes;    

var qualifiedRecs = await (from px in searchQuery
                           join ecx in entityCodesRepo on px.EntityCodeID equals ecx.EntityCodeID
                           select new IDMS_PartnerDTO //it doesn't belong to context
                           {
                               EntityType = ecx.DisplayLabel
                           }).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error. The entity or complex type 'IDMS_Partner' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Is there a way i can just update the EntityType property after getting the result using Linq

Comment: Does `IDMS_Partner` belong to `DbContext`?

Comment: No, its just a partial class

Comment: Add the class structure to the main question body.

Comment: Ok, thanks but I can see that it *does* belong to context and this is *not* supported in EF 6. So use a DTO class, anonymous type or return `entityCodesRepo ` or `searchQuery` entity type. After `ToListAsync` you can project it to any type you like though.